# Installing SecAst on AsteriskNOW with CentOS

Tags: centos, security, asterisk

Having some issues installing SecAst for IPS,

Followed the directions up to 2.1.6 and found a way (on this forum) to install qt5-qtbase (thanks) but when I run ldd /usr/local/secast/secast the return is "not a dynamic executable". I unpacked and installed -x86_64-rh6 tarball .. any suggestions?

Also there are directions in 2.1.9  to make a directory structure with /etx/xdg .. is this a typo and should it be /etc/xdg .. /etc/xdg/generationd ? If not where does the directory go under /etc/ ?

Also in /usr/local/secast/ there appears to be a secast file but when secast --help is run return is command not found. Files unpacked with no errors (re-unpacked to be sure), and the color of the font is green.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The message "not a dynamic executable" means that either you are checking the wrong file, or something is wrong with the secast executable.  First make sure you are checking the right file.

Did you unpack the package in Windows and then copy to Linux?  If not, post the results of running 'ls' in your /usr/local/secast folder.

There was a typo in the manual, the configuration file should be in the directory /etc/xdg/generationd

Your final issue is a basic linux syntax issue; to run a file (not in the path) you must give a path.  So instead, try to run

```
./secast
```

Comment: Hi Michelle, I used the tried both, first copied it from the web to windows then transferred to the VM by mounting a USB and copying. Then I deleted the directories and files, and used the wget command with the hyperlink to the x86_64 from your webpage in quotes. I then unpacked using tar -vxf 'file' and re-made the directories and re-copied over using the manual steps.

Comment: running the ls command in the /usr/local/secast folder returns with two listings in the directory [root@localhost secast]# ls ---> geoip.db secast 'one is white text the other is green text' ...running the command [root@localhost secast]# ./secast ----> -bash: ./secast: cannot execute binary file    the downloaded tar ball from your site is:secast-1.0.4.0-x86_64-rh6.tar.gz there were no errors unpacking.

Comment: It's a bit hard to read the comment - I'd suggest editing the question to add new info.  So what message do you see when you type './secast' ?

Comment: Well I started from scratch again just to check, there appears to be a newer file on your website: secast-1.0.6.0-x86_64-rh6.tar.gz . I used the command wget -v "http://www.generationd.com/Include/PHP/FileDownload.php?type=secast&name=secast-1.0.6.0-x86_64-rh6.tar.gz . This downloads the file in the /usr/src/ directory but the name is the entire string of 'FileDownload.php?type=secast.....-x86_64-rh6.tar.gz' I cp the file to the correct name where I unpack it using tar -xvf 'secast-1.0.6.0-x86_64.tar.gz and everything seems to unpack fine, no errors. I then follow the directions in the guide.

Comment: When I type './secast' the return response is: 'cannot execute binary file' but the text color is green for the 'secast' file in the folder.

Comment: I am not sure if this matters but I am running on Oracle VirtualBox VM using Linux as the type and Red Hat (64) bit as the version. I then installed AsteriskNOW PBX server (CentOS) into it as a 'guest' operating system.

Answer (score 0):

The comments below all support that this is not SecAst related, something else is going wrong on your computer.  Have a look at:

[Insufficient memory causing LDD issues](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/75054/ldd-tells-me-my-app-is-not-a-dynamic-executable)

The LDD issues and BASH issues all could be memory related, or a bad install of Linux....nothing SecAst related.